# How to place two controls in a good way

Tags: forms, buttons, input-fields, input, ux-field

I have no advanced UX experience and need some help in placing one input and one button on a whole screen. Is there any way to do it pretty? There will not be any other controls on that screen.

[image]

Comment: A little context would be helpful. What do people want to do on this page? What comes before? What comes after?

Comment: Yes, a little bit of context would be helpful. Can you put this form on modal instead of a new screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users read from top to bottom, therefore, I would recommend moving the button to below the field. For example:
[image]

Typeform has alot of beautiful and usable forms for you to reference:
https://www.typeform.com/templates/